# Clearing Output Window in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, window

How do I clear the output window in NetBeans?

I mean the window where the `"System.out.print"` prints.

I tried doing:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I clear the output window, then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click the console window and click clear.

Have a look here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2008/08/clearing-output-window-in-netbeans.html

Comment: That works, but the console input has been disabled. How do I enable it again? (Using BufferedReader)